# Finding the query execution path?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a legacy java web application where I have employee hibernate entity. Somehow in a particular flow, a query(HQL) is getting fired by hibernate to
 fetch employee entity. I tried my best to find out where/why exactly that query is firing but did not find why.

Is there a way hibernate can tell me where and why that query is executing ? Is there any kind of configuration/setting like  auditing which can help
 here ?

I am using hibernate version 5.1

Answer (score 0):

You could set a breakpoint in some suitable place in Hibernate code, then run the flow and see where its hit. Then you can find the user code that caused it to happen in the stacktrace.

The suitable place would be somewhere that manipulates the `User` entity, but this means you need to understand some of the inner workings of Hibernate to identify such a place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `use_sql_comments` or create empty constructor and put debug point there as suggested at [finding origin of query](https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-debugging-where-does)